# Xdebug does not work on a running or suspended queue. But it works when I just start the queue

Tags: php, debugging, profiling, xdebug

1. When i only running queue it works
   [image]
2. But, when i suspend the queue and run again it do not work
   [image]

CLI Setting

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_host=172.17.0.1 remote_port=9000 remote_connect_back=0
```

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-e2lQJrdQk)

Comment: **1)** Please describe your issue in a bit of details / to clarify the difference between "1 and 2" **2)** Your Xdebug version (just in case) **3)** Just in case: Xdebug communicates with IDE at the start of the script / when it awaits commands from debug client. So, for example, if you set the breakpoint when code is already running (in the middle of it) ... well, it will not do that (as it has no comms at that stage).

Comment: @LazyOne 1) When I run the command php artisan queue:work --queue=high,imageImport  the breakpoint works. When the queue is executed. The queue will wait for new jobs and breakpoints on new jobs do not stop. In this case, they are marked with ticks without stopping.  2) 2.9.8

Comment: Thanks. Still needs more info: what exactly do you mean "new jobs"? As I understand they were added to the queue later, after the queue was started and did the existing pending tasks? Or that means that you have created a new job code/edited the code or set/unset breakpoints after that? To be honest: the best way for me to understand this is to see it in action (some screencast: here it works ... but 20 secs later when all done and new job is added it is no longer stops" or whatever you are doing there.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking: the process that was executing that old jobs has quit / new one does not have the debug session established. The "breakpoint with the green tick" means that the Xdebug has confirmed that the breakpoint is set in that debug session. If you have added that breakpoint when queue is already running .. then it can be sent to Xdebug ONLY  when it awaits for commands (execution is paused: e.g. on start up or when breakpoint is hit).

Comment: Try this: add `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code -- it will act as a programmatic breakpoint and should  trigger the new debug session if none present. I also suggest enabling Xdebug log and check it for details: if the debug session is still live there etc. P.S. I personally did not debug the **live** queues this way so cannot say what nuances it may have (I've only had cases that can also be run/triggered as a normal script or on a fresh queue = easier debugging)

Comment: @LazyOne I run the command php artisan queue:work --queue=high,imageImport the breakpoint works. 
Then I remove the breakpoint. And I press to continue the execution. All queue jobs completed successfully. I am adding a breakpoint. The queue process is running, I didn't delete it. I am running php artisan import: price. This command adds jobs to the queue. The process listens for this and continues to execute. But now the breakpoint doesn't work.

Comment: *" the breakpoint works. Then I remove the breakpoint. And I press to continue the execution. All queue jobs completed successfully. I am adding a breakpoint."* OK. So based on my understanding of your description I can say that this confirms my words: you are adding breakpoints when Xdebug is not in "awaiting command" mode (which is on start up / when execution is paused).

Comment: Such breakpoint cannot be sent to Xdebug at that moment. Imagine this: you have some endless loop and trying to put a breakpoint when the loop is running. It will not work as execution is not paused and Xdebug cannot (or will not) accept it. You either keep breakpoint enabled all the time or restart your queue (run it again).

Comment: **P.S.** PhpStorm has conditional breakpoints: breakpoint is hit every time but based on the condition that you set up the IDE may ignore it and tell Xdebug to continue the execution and only break when the condition is met. try it -- maybe it will work for your case. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-breakpoints.html#properties

Comment: @LazyOne i added Video link on youtube in my post

Comment: Thanks for the video. So I did understood your words/explanation correctly and my knowledge of Xdebug tells that such approach does not work with Xdebug (although it may have such possibility).You can read on how it all works on Xdebug website if you have time: https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp. Plus, maybe @Derick (Xdebug author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/508057/derick) can give you a better/more authoritative answer on that.

Comment: @LazyOne I also wanted to ask. it is possible to use xdebug with cron ? Breakpoint no works, if i run cron. I am using cron for Laravel schedule

Comment: Yes. You can configure Xdebug to try and debug **every single request** .. or add needed PHP params to the executed command. For example: `php artisan do:some:task` is a normal command. With Xdebug params (for your 2.9.8) it would be something like `php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=0 artisan do:some:task`. Another option: add `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code (still requires correct PHP/Xdebug config, just without explicit "debug every request" or "debug me" flags)

Comment: In PhpStorm create Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Script" type to run/debug your `php artisan do:some:task` command (where `artisan` is the script/file to execute and `do:some:task` goes into parameter field) and click "Debug" button -- in the Console tab you will see that actual command that IDE executes (it should be adding those xdebug params to the command line by default) 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#debugging-framework-cli-command-results-in-php-errors 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html#debugging-artisan-commands

Comment: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` is for "try and debug every single request" -- https://2.xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_autostart

Comment: @LazyOne artisan commands work well. 
breakpoints called in Schedule do not work. 
* * * * * laradock /usr/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @LazyOne When called in CLI it works. When this call the cron don't work.

Comment: It has to be either explicit "debug me now" params or "debug every script" PHP/Xdebug config. Plus, the IDE must be in "Listen for incoming Xdebug connections" mode (the green phone handle icon must be ON). If it does not work: check the params / see what Xdebug log has to say etc. I do not use sail or Laradock myself so cannot give precise instructions for that. I suggest checking here (https://learnxdebug.com/) + google for "laradock xdebug" -- there should be articles/posts on such aspects.

Comment: @LazyOne Search: xdebug cron laravel schedule. Not results

Comment: @LazyOne i can make a video

Comment: Sorry .. no solid ideas right now. Perhaps it needs a server name as one of the params (as PhpStorm ignores such request since it may not know what project/connection to use)? You definitely need the Xdebug log for this: to see if it even tried to connect anywhere and what the response is. You need to ensure that Xdebug sees and tries to debug it first.